# Merging dataframes in Pandas but dealing with 'non-existent' columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a question regarding merging dataframes.

I have created a dataframe with three empty columns, named USD, EUR, GBP.

```
  group   USD   EUR   GBP
0     A  None  None  None
1     B  None  None  None
2     C  None  None  None
```

I now would like to fill in values for these columns, based on the USD, EUR, GBP values that I have saved in another dataframe, for example:

```
  group   USD   EUR   GBP
0     A   NaN  0.05  0.04
1     B  0.04   NaN  0.03
2     C  0.02   NaN  0.01
```

Why am I not just merging based on 'group' ? Because the value dataframe would not always show three columns but two columns instead, for example:

```
  group   USD   EUR
0     A   NaN  0.05
1     B  0.04   NaN
2     C  0.02   NaN
```

The issue here is that I would like to see all three columns in the final output, regardless of whether data of a particular column exists or not. So the final output, using the third table as 'data table' should look like this:

```
  group   USD   EUR  GBP
0     A   NaN  0.05  NaN
1     B  0.04   NaN  NaN
2     C  0.02   NaN  NaN
```

Do you have any ideas on how to tackle this? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Could you clarify the question? Do you really just want the output dataframe to be a copy of the values df, with possibly some empty columns added? If so, can you copy and add the columns you need.

Comment: I replaced your images by reproducible inputs, please double check that the format is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can align and [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
out = (df1.set_index('group')
          .combine_first(df2.set_index('group'))
          .reset_index()
      )
```

Or [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
out = df1[['group']].merge(df2, how='left').reindex(columns=df1.columns)
```

Output:

```
# case 1
  group   USD   EUR   GBP
0     A   NaN  0.05  0.04
1     B  0.04   NaN  0.03
2     C  0.02   NaN  0.01

# case 2
  group   USD   EUR  GBP
0     A   NaN  0.05  NaN
1     B  0.04   NaN  NaN
2     C  0.02   NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question it seems you might simply want to join a `how = 'outer'` to your merge:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_value_base = pd.DataFrame({
    'USD' : [],
    'EUR' : [],
    'GBP' : []
})
 

df_value_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'USD' : [np.nan, .04, .02],
    'EUR' : [.05, np.nan, np.nan],
    'GBP' : [.04, .03, .01]
})

df_value_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'USD' : [np.nan, .04, .02],
    'GBP' : [.04, .03, .01]
})

df_value_3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'EUR' : [.05, np.nan, np.nan],
    'GBP' : [.04, .03, .01]
})

df_value_base.merge(df_value_1, how = 'outer')

df_value_base.merge(df_value_2, how = 'outer')
```